# How to Calculate Indoors Feels Like Temperature for All Seasons?

Tags: temperature

I want to calculate "feels like" temperature indoors, with no sunlight or wind. But I don't know which method to use or if I should combine methods. Below I've given some research results I obtained but the correct method can be something else.

- [Heat Index Calculation](https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/html/heatindex_equation.shtml) looks promising but I know it is mostly used for high temperatures. At least there are adjustments for low temperatures as well.
- There is also "apparent temperature" calculation given as:

AT = Ta + .348*e - .70*ws + .70*(Q/ws + 10) - 4.25

- Where AT is the apparent temperature (C)
- Ta is the dry bulb temperature (C)
- e is the humidity (hPa)
- ws is the wind speed (m/s)
- Q is the net radiation absorbed per unit of body surface area

I can substitude zero for ws but even then I don't know Q value thus I am not sure if I can use this.

- There is WetBulb Globe Temperature (WBGT) but it is for outdoor (i guess) because it involves sunlight.

Comment: For indoor use, you need to consider the radiative temperature of the walls, floor, and ceiling.  Outdoor equations (that aren't very scientific to begin with) are not suitable.  A 21°C room can feel surprisingly cold when the walls are at 13°C. I'm not an expert at all, but for pointers, see [operative temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operative_temperature) and [mean radiant temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_radiant_temperature) on Wikipedia.